What should the next step be in this Kakuro puzzle?
I have recently been learning more and more tricks for solving Kakuro puzzles, but I'm at a loss for how to solve the final bit of this puzzle. For reference, it is from the "Real Kakuro" app, Challenging #17. What is the next logical step for what I have solved?


There are multiple solutions to this puzzle, so there is no logical conclusion to be found.

There is one possible deduction:

 See vertical 13 and horizontal 11 at the bottom. Top cell of 13 and right-side cell of 11 are paired to be (6, 4) or (4, 2), so the cell right of top of 13 cannot be 4.

But it ends there. Using a computer program, I confirmed that every candidate in every cell in the image below is part of some potential solution. There are 24 solutions in total. Turns out that you incorrectly erased a few candidates you cannot eliminate.

 


So what you're saying is that the next logical step after that is to get a better Kakuro app?

Maybe yeah lol. Or take this as an opportunity to check out other [tag:grid-deduction] genres, such as nurikabe, slitherlink, hashi, star battle, tents and trees, kuromasu (there are high quality apps for all of these, at least on android).
